# Notification of User Opening other NSStatusItem's Menu on a Mac

Tags: macos, nswindow, nsstatusitem

I'm writing a mac app that sits in the menu bar and presents the user with a `NSPanel` instance when they click the status item. I want to hide the window whenever another status item's menu is opened. Right now, my panel stays open; it looks like this:

[image: My app is on the left, attached to the infinity status item]

I see other applications like mine close when another status item opens its menu, so I'm wonder which notification they're getting to know to disappear. I've looked into `NSWindowDelegate` and `NSApplicationDelegate`, but I don't see any notifications being generated.

Have any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured it out! In the `awakeFromNib`, I was setting the properties of my `NSPanel` instance. I was using the following:

```
[panel setStyleMask:panel.styleMask ^ NSTitledWindowMask];
```

Switching it to the following:

```
[panel setStyleMask:(panel.styleMask ^ NSTitledWindowMask ^ NSNonactivatingPanelMask)];
```

Did the trick. I figured it out after reading [Neil Inglis' blog post](http://www.neilinglis.com/2010/02/07/maattachedwindownon-activating-panel/) on using MAAttachedWindow in a similar way.